# Restore Safari browser on MacBook Air Yosemite OSX 10.10.4

Tags: macos

How do I restore my Safari browser.  I accidentally deleted it. Now I have to use Google or Bing.  Whoops!

Comment: The only way I know is to use OS X restore with "cmd+r" that will restore the installation, since the Safari is integrated part of it.

Comment: How did you "_accidentally_" delete it?

Comment: You might want to re-install the [10.10.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to see if that re-installs Safari, too.

Comment: Did you "Delete" it or just remove it from the Dock?  Go to your Applications folder, if it is there, drag it back to your dock.

Answer (score 1):

Many who are new to the Mac and OS X mistakenly think they have deleted something if they accidentally or purposely remove a icon from the **Dock**.

If that is what you have done, restoring it to the **Dock** is easily done.

- Find your **Applications** folder
- Locate **Safari**
- Drag to the dock

Or, double click on it and it will open.  There you can pin it to the **Dock**. By long pressing the icon or right clicking and select options.  See screenshot below.  The other way to keep it there is simply to drag it to a new location on the **Dock** closer to the **Finder** icon.

If you dragged it to the **Trash** from the Applications folder, the open the trash folder by double clicking on it and restoring from there.

If you ***truly*** deleted it, which is very hard to do "accidentally", a restore of your OS may be in order.

[image: Pin to dock]